# Custom VF Header/UI on Standard Page Layouts

Tags: visualforce

I've tried googling, but only found things related to older Portal functionality.  Maybe I'm using the wrong search words.

Here's a screenshot... I want to replace the header shown at the top of all pages with a VF page.  The reason:  Want to add some custom buttons/fields/etc there.  Can anyone guide me to a starting point there?  (arrows point to what I want to replace).

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately you can not do that in a org level. You can only change the image/logo as below.

1. Click on:

Setup | App Setup | Customize | Home | Home Page Components.

2. Create a new custom component and follow the directions to save an image.
3. Once the image is saved, click on the "Home Page Layouts" link located under "Home Page Components".
4. Create a new layout and click "Save".
5. Ensure that 'company logo' is selected, and then click "Next".
6. In step 2, move 'company logo' to the top of the left column (Narrow).
7. Click "Save & Assign" to assign this page layout to the profiles you would like to have the logo displayed for.